Problem with format in verse enviroment
I have taken on the task of gathering several poems. I had written individual poems in LaTeX without any problem, but now I find myself with this that I don't know how to solve:

It seems that the verses on the next page are further behind than those above, but I don't know why.
This is my code:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks, colorlinks=false, hidelinks}{hyperref}
% Use PoetryTeX; http://www.ctan.org/pkg/poetrytex
\usepackage[numberpoems, clearpageafterpoem, useincipits]{poetrytex}

% Use the PA5 paper size
\usepackage[paperwidth=140mm,paperheight=210mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\pttitle}{Fragmentos}
\renewcommand{\ptsubtitle}{Mostly by people.}
%\renewcommand{\ptauthor}{Someone}
%\renewcommand{\ptdate}{\today}
\renewcommand{\ptdedication}{dedication...//line 2// line 3}
\newcommand{\attrib}[1]{%
\nopagebreak{\raggedleft\footnotesize #1\par}}


\begin{document}


\maketitle
\makededication

% Number pages with small roman numerals (i, ii, iii, iv...)
\frontmatter

% TOC %
\maketoc

% TOP %
\renewcommand*{\topname}{Poemas} % Name for the table of poems
\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{Para la lectora}
prologo de ejemplo ... ... ...
\newpage

\
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

% Start numbering pages with normal arabic numerals.
%\mainmatter


\section{Poemas}
\poemtitle{Tres mil latidos y doscientos litros de sangre}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{como el rizo que se enredara entre dos dedos} % Ajusta esto según el largo de la línea más larga

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]
Si pudiera multiplicarme \\ 
pasearía contigo \\ 
dándote las dos manos. \\!

Quiero decir, \\
si pudiera ser dos yo, \\
yo dos veces \\
—entiéndeme—, \\
un alma repetida \\
como el rizo que se enredara entre dos dedos \\
y pareciera un meñique \\ 
o los labios \\
que abrieran paso a una lengua \\
que precediera a un beso \\
que se duplicara buscando la eternidad, \\
colonizaría tu hoy y tu mañana, \\
te esperaría donde estarías \\
y donde querrías estar, \\
te extrañaría \\
viendo cómo tus besos crean goteras en mis pestañas \\
y al mismo tiempo te dibujaría labios \\
llenos de saliva \\
en el centro de tu dedo corazón. \\!

Si pudiera redoblarme \\
nos observaría desde fuera \\
como quien mira a los ojos de la muerte: \\
con envidia. \\!
\newpage

Si pudiera estar aquí y allí \\
estaría en ti y en ti, \\
prendería fuego a Troya \\
mientras te regalo París, \\
te miraría dormir \\
y al mismo tiempo soñaría contigo. \\!

Ya sabes a lo que me refiero, \\ 
si pudiera engañar a las coordenadas \\
crearía un mapa donde solo cupieran \\
tus dedos de los pies \\
y esta necesidad mía de seguirte a todas partes. \\!

Si pudiera ser la misma en dos mitades, \\
amor, \\
te vestiría con el mismo nerviosismo \\
con el que me dejas desnudarte, \\
limaría mis errores \\
para que el tropiezo fuera suave \\
y sería a la vez precipicio e impulso \\
de todos tus miedos y sueños. \\!

Si pudiera, \\
mi amor, \\
convertiría todo lo que ahora es singular \\
en plural. \\!

Pero no puedo, \\
así que has de conformarte \\
con lo único que puedo hacer: 
quererte \\
—no el doble, ni por dos, ni al cuadrado, \\
sino con la fuerza de un ejército \\
de tres mil latidos y doscientos litros de sangre \\
que queriéndote dar más de lo que tiene \\
te da todo lo que es—. \\!
\end{verse}
\attrib{Elvira Sastre}

\end{document}


What changes when you add oneside to your document load (i.e., \documentclass[oneside,...]{book})?

Odd numbered and even numbered pages have different left margins.

@Werner The word oneside in \documentclass worked perfectly.

@egreg Apparently, the question was answered a few years ago, but can you explain your comment? the Odd and even pages with different margins

@isc oneside is not the answer, that's what I mean to say. And I was writing an answer when the thread was untimely closed.

Possible duplicate: When using a book class (memoir), text shifts from left to right on each page

It's not a problem with verse.
If I add \lipsum[1-20] (with \usepackage{lipsum} just for experimenting, I get this page break between pages IV and V

You can see that the inner margin (right on even-numbered pages and left on odd-numbered pages) is smaller than the outer margin.
This is the standard setting for most books.
Now let's also add showframe to the options for geometry and look at the facing pages IV and V

You clearly see that the left edge of the verses has the same distance from the left margin of the text block in either page.
A book is supposed to be looked at open. If your printout is meant to be looked at on a screen, then use the oneside class option, so geometry will make equal left and right margins (in this case “inner” and “outer” don't mean a thing).


Thank you for the explanation. You saved me because I plan to print this document; I was unaware of that small but important detail regarding the margins in books.
